# Basic JAVA console based menu problem

Tags: java

I am trying to make a basic java console based menu system. I have managed to get the first tier working fine:

```
public static int menu(){

    //Displays the main menu and handles passing off to next menu. 

      Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
      int selection=0;
      String CDid;
      int i=0;
      int j=0;

      while(i==0) {   //changed while(1) to a value that didn't complain in netbeans
          System.out.println("Please choose an option from the following:"); 
          System.out.println("[1] Search by CD ID"); 
          System.out.println("[2] View all CD's in store"); 
          System.out.println("[3] Quit"); 
          System.out.println("Choice: "); 
          selection=scanner.nextInt();     

     switch (selection){

         case 1:System.out.println("Please enter the CD ID:");
              i=1;
              break;       

         case 2:System.out.println("List all CD's");
              i=1;
              break;

         case 3:System.out.println("Quiting...");
              System.exit(5);

         default:System.out.println("Your choice was not valid!");

          };

      }  
      return selection;
  }
```

I am now trying to make it so that when you choose option [1] it takes the next string you input and runs the showCD() method. I have tried the method I used before but as it's a string I am hitting some errors.

```
  public static int menu(){
        //Displays the main menu and handles passing off to next menu. 

          Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
          int selection=0;
          String CDid;
          int i=0;
          int j=0;

          while(i==0) {   //changed while(1) to a value that didn't complain in netbeans
              System.out.println("Please choose an option from the following:"); 
              System.out.println("[1] Search by CD ID"); 
              System.out.println("[2] View all CD's in store"); 
              System.out.println("[3] Quit"); 
              System.out.println("Choice: "); 
              selection=scanner.nextInt();     

         switch (selection){

             case 1:System.out.println("Please enter the CD ID:");
                    CDid=scanner.toString(); 
                      while(j==0) { 
                         switch (CDid){
                         case 1:showCD(CDid);
                         j=1;
                         break;

                         default:System.out.println("Your choice was not valid!");

                         }
                      }

                  i=1;
                  break;       

             case 2:System.out.println("List all CD's");
                  i=1;
                  break;

             case 3:System.out.println("Quiting...");
                  System.exit(5);

             default:System.out.println("Your choice was not valid!");

              };

          }  
          return selection;
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like homework (you should tag it as such).  You're trying to get the next String of user input but your code is calling `scanner.toString()`.  This will merely print out the String representation of the Scanner object.  You may want to use `scanner.nextLine()` instead.  Take a look at [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for reference.

**EDIT**: Also, just reading further through your code, you're then trying to switch on CDid which is a String.  You can't switch on a String in Java (yet if you're <= 1.6).  You would need an if-else block here instead.

Answer (score 0):

change: CDid=scanner.toString();

to: CDid=scanner.next();

I am not so sure that you can make a switch with a String... if you can't parse CDid to Integer with Integer.parseInt() method

Comment: There is no nextString method on Scanner.  (This is in 1.6 anyway).